# Changing default action doesn't work for ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

On latest ASP.NET MVC CORE 2 default template, i am trying to change default action by modifying controller and action as below. I am expecting to see login page as default but i am having 404 http error. What I am doing wrong ?

You can verify this issue on default ASP.NET CORE 2 MVC project.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: include the controller and target action in the question. The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Nikosi Did you try this in default ASP.NET Core template ? It works fine for you ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the `AccountController` class, you'll see it's decorated with a `Route` attribute, like so:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

However, if you look at the `HomeController` class, you'll see that it is *not* decorated with such an attribute:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Because the `AccountController` is using [Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing), it will not be picked up using the [Conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#conventional-routing) template. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing) explain this mutual exclusivity:

> Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the conventional routes and vice-versa.

Comment: Serpent beat me to the explanation, but the solution if you want to do it anyways is to remove the `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]` line from AccountController