# MVC Request did not match any routes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have following controller where I need to find routes for various actions:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> Get()
    {
        return await _userService.GetAllAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<User> Get(object id)
    {
        return await _userService.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == (ObjectId)id);
    }
}
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

such request http://localhost:55556/User/Get should be passed to a route but I get the following message when running in Visual Studio debug:

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55556/User/Get  
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware[1]
Request did not match any routes.
```

What could be wrong here? Is there any way to list all possible routes? Or make sure what controllers are registered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing default action doesn't work for ASP.NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713292/changing-default-action-doesnt-work-for-asp-net-core-2) - See my answer for that question for an explanation as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look on your route template definition more carefully:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

It has a `api/` string prefix (const) and so MVC middleware experts requests like

```
http://localhost:55556/api/User/Get
```

not

```
http://localhost:55556/User/Get
```

---

Also, if talking in the scope of REST, it is a bad idea to use routes like `User/GET`, `User/POST` etc. For such purpose, the corresponding HTTP Method (Gey, Post, Put, ...) is defined and used. In other words, you have a redundant duplication right now, as a request, for example, from curl looks like:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:55556/User/Get`
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very embrassing mistake by my part. This question can be deleted since it is not a real problem.